# How to use ADB to send touch events to device using sendevent command?

Tags: android, automation, adb, touchscreen

I am trying to send touch events to a device using AndroidDebugBridge, so that I can do some basic automation for UI tests. I have followed the discussion in [LINK](http://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_thread/thread/8a5d8fa9229114d2/ce6e604f52b5318f?pli=1). I am able to use sendevent to simulate touch on emulators, but unable to do the same on a device.

Like in above link the emulator seems to send out 6 events for each touch ( xcoord, ycoord, 2 for press,2 for release) and it was easy to use this information to sendevents, but a getevent for the touchscreen for a device seems to generate far too many events.

Has somebody managed to send touch from ADB to a device? Could you please share the solution.

Comment: On the device, did you check if you are passing the events to the proper "input-device"? ie. the input-device which is registered as the touch-driver?

Answer (score 171, accepted):

Android comes with an `input` command-line tool that can simulate miscellaneous input events. To simulate tapping, it's:

```
input tap x y
```

You can use the adb shell ( > 2.3.5) to run the command remotely:

```
adb shell input tap x y
```

Comment: It works perfectly on Nox App using nox_adb.exe thank you!

Comment: For Testing double tap i wrote a loop click like this i=0; while [ $(($i)) -le 2 ]; do i=$(($i + 1)); input tap 500 800; done; But it is clicking the place every one second. can i do it faster using terminal?

Comment: Any way to long press too?

Comment: It's working as required. Thanks for this help

Answer (score 90):

In order to do a particular action (for example to open the web browser), you need to first figure out where to tap.  To do that, you can first run:

```
adb shell getevent -l
```

Once you press on the device, at the location that you want, you will see this output:

```
<...>
/dev/input/event3: EV_KEY       BTN_TOUCH            DOWN
/dev/input/event3: EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    000002f5
/dev/input/event3: EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    0000069e
```

adb is telling you that a key was pressed (button down) at position 2f5, 69e in hex which is 757 and 1694 in decimal.

If you now want to generate the same event, you can use the input tap command at the same position:

```
adb shell input tap 757 1694
```

More info can be found at:

https://source.android.com/devices/input/touch-devices.html
http://source.android.com/devices/input/getevent.html

Comment: To find the touch co-ordinates, I would recommend using Developer Options --> Show Touch Location. Also, it gives the values in decimals.

Comment: If you don't want to have to convert the hex to decimal, you can let your shell do it: `adb shell input tap $((16#2f5)) $((16#69e))`. Also, just to be pedantic, 0x2F5 and 0x69E are 757 and 1694 respectively... What did you use to convert between bases?

Comment: Thanks @ghoti not sure I must have copied it off another point or something like that...

Comment: Building on top of this I built the command ```adb shell getevent -l | grep ABS_MT_POSITION --line-buffered | awk '{a = substr($0,54,8); sub(/^0+/, "", a); b = sprintf("0x%s",a); printf("%d\n",strtonum(b))}'``` that gets the tap position as an integer

Answer (score 13):

2.3.5 did not have `input tap`, just `input keyevent` and `input text`
You can use the monkeyrunner for it: (this is a copy of the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/18959385/1587329):

> You might want to use [monkeyrunner](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html) like this:

```
$ monkeyrunner
>>> from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice
>>> device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()
>>> device.touch(200, 400, MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)
```

> You can also do a drag, start activies etc.
>   Have a look at the api for [MonkeyDevice](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/MonkeyDevice.html).

Answer (score 10):

Building on top of Tomas's answer, this is the best approach of finding the location tap position as an integer I found:

```
adb shell getevent -l | grep ABS_MT_POSITION --line-buffered | awk '{a = substr($0,54,8); sub(/^0+/, "", a); b = sprintf("0x%s",a); printf("%d\n",strtonum(b))}'
```

Use `adb shell getevent -l` to get a list of events, the using grep for `ABS_MT_POSITION` (gets the line with touch events in hex) and finally use awk to get the relevant hex values, strip them of zeros and convert hex to integer. This continuously prints the x and y coordinates in the terminal only when you press on the device.

You can then use this adb shell command to send the command:

```
adb shell input tap x y
```

Comment: Your answer is great, can we use this command to further send those integers to another device like reading touch events from a physical keyboard and at the same time using sendevents we can forward those to another virtual keyboard

Comment: But one touch prints 6 numbers!
7150
6984
7147
6974
7143
6964

and if you press harder, it prints more! Can we pass a sequence of x y in one `tap` command?

Comment: ```
awk: calling undefined function strtonum
 input record number 1, file 
 source line number 1
```

Answer (score 9):

You don't need to use

> adb shell getevent -l

command, you just need to enable in Developer Options on the device [Show Touch data] to get X and Y.

Some more information can be found in my article here: https://mobileqablog.wordpress.com/2016/08/20/android-automatic-touchscreen-taps-adb-shell-input-touchscreen-tap/

Answer (score 4):

Consider using Android's [uiautomator](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/index.html), with adb shell uiautomator [...] or directly using the .jar that comes with the SDK.

Comment: BTW, there are a few tools on the market that can make Android's Automation testing quite easier for you.