# Disable Slide to Unlock

Tags: adb

I have a Velocity Cruz T301 which is rooted. The screen calibration is a bit off and I cannot access the home screen. (It is next to impossible to use the slide to unlock.) Basically, it will slide to the right, but not far enough to unlock. I know that the app "nolock" will correct this problem, but since I cannot even access the home screen, I am unsure how to turn on this app.

I have tried three different ROMS (Official Cruz, SJHill, and the Davik.)

If I could find the ADB shell command to disable the slide lock, I think I could save this tablet. I have tried the adb shell input keyevent 82, but it will not work.

I also have Android Commander installed on my PC. With this I can install apps, just not access the features.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To unlock, type

```
adb shell monkey --pct-motion 100 100
```

This will send 100 pseudo-random swipe events to the device ;-)

For this, you need to have pushed the power button so that it is active. (there sure exists a keypress event for that too)

For more sophistication, have a look at the (unrelated) monkeyrunner:
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html

Once the slide is unlocked, if you still have problems tapping the app to start it, have a look at [how-to-use-adb-to-send-touch-events-to-device-using-sendevent-command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437686/how-to-use-adb-to-send-touch-events-to-device-using-sendevent-command/18959654#18959654).