# To parse an Android application?

Tags: android

Is there some external (or internal) script library to start an android app, to parse, to get the text displayed by the app and to perform clicks in order to build some kind of bot user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can simulate touches, using ADB. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437686/how-to-use-adb-to-send-touch-events-to-device-using-sendevent-command). From the link:

> You can use the adb shell to run the command remotely:
>
> ```
> adb shell input tap x y
> ```

If you want to get the text from the screen, you could get a screenshot from the device, (again using ADB). To get screenshot with ADB:

```
adb shell screencap -p /sdcard/screen.png
adb pull /sdcard/screen.png
adb shell rm /sdcard/screen.png
```

See [here](http://blog.shvetsov.com/2013/02/grab-android-screenshot-to-computer-via.html) for source, and what to do if it doesn't work right.

Then you would need to send the screenshot through an OCR program to extract the text.

There is probably an easier way to do this, for example if there is a website for the app, you could just scrape the information from that.