# Paste text on Android using ADB?

Tags: android, adb, copy-paste

This might seem like a duplicate question, but hear me out.

I basically need to press "CTRL+V" inside of Android. I need to paste the current Android clipboard into the focused TextBox.

So this:

```
adb shell input text [text]
```

won't do, as it requires me to enter the text myself. I just need to paste the current clipboard.

Is that possible through ABD? I googled and googled and all I found was ways to set clipboard content and not actually just press the paste button.

*for the sake to ease development*

Comment: @adelphus the clipboard on the device. As you would just "CTRL+V" on windows, I just need to "CTRL+V" on Android if you know what I mean.

Comment: Not directly through adb. If you have root, you could create a background system service that responds to an intent, and upon receiving the intent, inject a key sequence equivalent to paste (Ctrl + V).

Comment: Since pasting is normally a hold and tap operation on the EditText, could you simulate taps in the appropriate positions - like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437686/how-to-use-adb-to-send-touch-events-to-device-using-sendevent-command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

1. I installed the Tasker plugin.
2. I made a "scene" with a button.
3. On the button tap event I added the "Control+V plugin" with the configuration to type `%CLIP`.
4. Now I made a profile that direct to a task to show the scene (overlay,blocking).
5. And last but not least, I use `adb shell input tap x y` to tap the button.

Answer (score 20):

Since API 24, `KEYCODE_PASTE` is available from the `KeyEvent` class, its constant is `279`.

The adb command would be as follows:

```
adb shell input keyevent 279
```

Comment: No responds why

Comment: This command is great! If you're also looking for a way to SET the clipboard over adb, you can install this app on your device: https://github.com/PRosenb/AdbClipboard. With this app you just need to broadcast a url encoded string and it will get set to the devices clipboard (works with spaces, special characters, emojis, etc).