# Have python interact with multiple android emulators

Tags: python, android, emulation

its a weird question and might not even be possible at all, but I'm still asking. I am looking for a way to automate certain tasks with python on multiple android emulators at once. So either a way to use commands to start emulators running certain scripts or some kind of container around the emulator that would be able to be controlled by python/ do certain clicks. I'm hoping someone knows a solution to this

Comment: I know this question is explained pretty bad, but it's hard to explain the problem

Comment: With `adb` you can do pretty much anything, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ADB](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) commands to control both real Android devices and emulators, so one option would be to call the `adb` binary using `subprocess` from Python.

It is possible to [emulate different input events using ADB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437686/how-to-use-adb-to-send-touch-events-to-device-using-sendevent-command) such as clicks, as well as start and stop apps and services, and much much more.

You can communicate with multiple devices as well sending different commands to each one.