# Auto click on phone screen at given position in java android

Tags: java, android

I want to automate click or taps
I want to perform click at given position in android using java language

My code until yet

private void performClickAtPosition(int x, int y) {

```
    // Create a MotionEvent to simulate a click at the specified position

    long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

    long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

    int action = MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN;

    MotionEvent motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, action, x, y, 0);

    // Find the target view at the specified coordinates

    View targetView = getWindow().getDecorView();

    

    // Dispatch the MotionEvent to the target view

    targetView.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);

    // Release the MotionEvent

    motionEvent.recycle();

}
```

But it is not working and it is only for click within the app

But I want to click on current phone screen
Also please explain permission required for this

Answer (score 0):

You can't click on another app from an Android app, for security reasons.  At least not unless you have a jailbroken phone.  You can do it via ADB if you need to automate some tests.  But there is no API to click on other apps.

Comment: If user give accessibility permission, it can be possible and did you hear about app named auto click - automate taps , it is on play Store

Comment: Accessibility is only allowed on the play store if you're doing actual accessibility things in your app.  I also believe it doesn't allow clicking at a point on screen, but allows you to interact with an on screen element.

Comment: Just like we use the robot object to perform mouse press for desktop applications, similarly I want to perform a click on current phone screen through my application

Comment: If it's through a desktop app, then consider using adb https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437686/how-to-use-adb-to-send-touch-events-to-device-using-sendevent-command.  As a bonus, that doesn't require an app on the phone.  If it's through an app on the phone there is no API to allow this, and that's done purposefully to prevent such applications.